# Value is not getting printed in Datasheet excel for setCellValue() using Selenium Apache POI Java webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

Value is not getting printed in Datasheet excel using Selenium Apache POI Java webdriver. Please help to print the value in the Datasheet excel.

Requirement is to pass sheet name, rownumber, Column number and text to be printed in the excel. By this code, text is not getting printed in Datasheet excel.

```
class ReadDataSheet:

public class ReadDataSheet {
public WebDriver dr;
public HSSFWorkbook wb;
public HSSFSheet ws;
public int rowCount;
public String className;
public String sheetName;
public String colName;
public String value;

public String setValue(String SheetName, String rowName, String columnHeader, String textToPrint) {

try {
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("./DataSheet.xls"));

wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

ws = wb.getSheet(SheetName);
int rownumber = getRownumber(rowName, columnHeader);
int columnNumber = getColumnNumber(columnHeader);
Cell cell;
cell = ws.getRow(rownumber).createCell(columnNumber);
            cell.setCellValue(textToPrint);

} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}

return value;


}

Class Login:
public class Login{
public ReadDataSheet rds = new ReadDataSheet();
public void printValue() throws Exception {
rds.setValue("data details","Test case 1","Page Title","Selenium")
}
}
Class TC_01:
public class TC_01 extends Login
{
                @Test
            public void page() throws Exception  
             {                                              
                Login login = new Login(remoteDriver);

                     login.printValue();

             }
}
```

Comment: What exactly means "text is not getting printed in Datasheet excel"? Are there any errors thrown? If not, the cell value probably is set. But all changes are in random access memory at first. So of course you also need write out the changed workbook then. See [Reading and Rewriting Workbooks](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook).

Comment: The text Selenium is not getting written in the excel. Could you please help me by correcting and to get print oin excel. Code does not throw error and not getting printed in excel.

Answer (score 2):

To write value to excel, you need to save the excel sheet. Using folloing snippet at the end of

> setValue method:

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("poi-generated-file.xlsx");
workbook.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();

// Closing the workbook
workbook.close();
```

Please share more details if it is not the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be in the `getRownumber(rowName, columnHeader);`  method.
Is there any particular reason why this method requires columnHeader as a parameter?
It should only take rowName as input.
Can you please publish the code for these two methods (getRownumber and getColumnNumber) as well as upload the data sheet format?